# Unable to modify registry keys using Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{fb397776-518e-4d12-9ba6-2087011c782e}\FxProperties
```

I am trying to modify a property's value on that registry key but I am getting error

> Requested registry access is not allowed.

When I try to set a rule for ACL on this key, I am getting the same error.

I am trying with this code

```
$ke = Get-Acl $KeyFxProperties.PSPath
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule("BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS","FullControl","Allow")
ke.SetAccessRule($rule)
$ke |Set-Acl -Path $KeyFxProperties.PSPath
```

Comment: Modifying entries in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry hive requires _elevation_ (run as admin).

Comment: I am running Powershell in elevated mode

Comment: That implies one of two things: (a) target key's ACL denies write access even to administrators or (b) the key was opened with read-only access.

Comment: I have added the script that I am trying to run. Just found that the registry key is owned by SYSTEM. Not sure how we can run the scripts as system

Comment: `psexec` can run as the system account on demand, for instance. Interactively, you can alternatively try to change ownership of the key and grant yourself permission, f appropriate.